# Would I get back all of HD memory if I remove partitioned-Ubuntu from my Windows system?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7

I've a system with this configuration :
- Dell Vostro 1015 laptop built Sept 2011
- Intel Core2 Duo processor @ 2 Ghz frequency
- 64-bit memory
- 320 GB HDD
- integrated graphics
- WiFi & bluetooth enabled

I'm currently using Windows 7 Ultimate OS since I bought it. I'm fed up of using Windows 7 on my system (& Windows 8 wont work !) so I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.04.
I've 2 questions :

- If I install it in partition with my current OS, and then after some time, if I need to remove Ubuntu from the system (without removing windows), will I get back all the HDD memory used by the Ubuntu OS and make it accessible to the Windows system (again) ?
- Can I use both the Operating Systems in such a way that I can access the hard disk data equally among both the OSes, that is, I can access the same HD data by both the OSes ?

(P.S. : I don't want to use Virtual OS software)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Well rather than uninstalling it, I'd delete the partition, to make it free space, and then expand the Windows partition into it, so yes, you could.

Unfortunately Ubuntu uses the `ext4` file system, and windows uses the `nfts` file system. You could (theoretically) access between them, but I'm not sure how good Windows is with ext.